# Flight schedules

Tags: air-travel, airlines, bookings, layovers, accommodation

I booked a return flight from Mumbai to Melbourne by Malaysia Airlines using a travel agency 'Budget Air' in September 2017. The return travel date is 17 April 2018. After confirming the travel schedule, Malaysia Airlines has revised the flight schedule from Kuala Lumpur to Mumbai to a flight on 18 Apr 2018 in the morning at 9 am, with a stopover of more than 12 hours in Kuala Lumpur over the night of 17 to 18 April 2018.

I'm 73 years old. To spend the night in Kuala Lumpur is the last thing that I wanted. I promptly asked them to either change my flight from MEL to KUL to a later flight reaching KUL in the morning of 18 April OR to provide a hotel accommodation at KUL airport for the night of 17 April. To say the least, the response from Malaysia Airlines was not helpful: I was to contact Budget Air. What do you suggest to do now?

Comment: Are you looking for accommodation suggestions? I doubt anyone here can help out regarding the budget air communication.

Answer (score 3):

You need to talk to Budget Air - they are the ticket issuer, the airline will not make changes to an agencies ticket as they have no contractual ability to do so.  Budget Air are the only ones who can change the ticket.

As the change is more than 4 months out, you are out of luck with regard to any compensation or accommodation entitlement - even the very strict EU rules (which do not apply here, but I am using them as an example) allow changes with no compensation this far out from the flight.

In short, you need to talk to Budget Air. Expect an offer to refund the ticket, but not much else.